# Is there a possibility to configure a fallback database write host to laravel instead of randomly choose connections to use?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

We have a Galera DB cluster running 3 nodes and a load balancer acting as a intermediary between the nodes. Our application running multiple instances and has a lot of read/writes to the database so we ran into problems with deadlocks when using the loadbalancer for writes. We workaround the problem by selecting one of the 3 nodes specific for writing and still using the loadbalancer for reading.

Now I'm looking for a solution to setup a fallback connection host when there is a problem connecting to the write node so we have no downtime.
I did a lot of research and i found out about this method in `Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory`:

```php
/**
 * Create a new Closure that resolves to a PDO instance with a specific host or an array of hosts.
 *
 * @param  array  $config
 * @return \Closure
 */
protected function createPdoResolverWithHosts(array $config)
{
    return function () use ($config) {
        foreach (Arr::shuffle($hosts = $this->parseHosts($config)) as $key => $host) {
            $config['host'] = $host;

            try {
                return $this->createConnector($config)->connect($config);
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                continue;
            }
        }

        throw $e;
    };
}
```

I can provide multiple hosts to the write configuration but Laravel will randomly decide which one to use.

```php
'write'     => [
    'host' => [ "node1", "node2" ],
],
```

I just want to always use 1 node for writes and if there is a problem with the connection i want to fallback to another one (second one).
Does somebody know how i could achieve this? It seems I can't override the behavior of `createPdoResolverWithHosts` as it's not a service provider, but coded in the core of Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So looking at the `Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory` class, your question includes the `createPdoResolverWithHosts()` method; you can see this is called by `createPdoResolver()` when a `hosts` key exists in the config. But if that array key is missing, `createPdoResolverWithoutHosts()` is called instead, which directly calls the `createConnector()` method. That method returns an instance of the appropriate database connector class. Before it does that, however, it checks for any bound connectors:

```php
if ($this->container->bound($key = "db.connector.{$config['driver']}")) {
    return $this->container->make($key);
}
```

So (with the caveat that this is completely untested) I would suggest the following:

Create a custom database connector, extending the default one. Put some custom logic into the `connect()` method, which gets the config array as its sole argument:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Database;

use Illuminate\Database\Connectors\MySqlConnector as BaseConnector;

class MySqlConnector extends BaseConnector
{
    public function connect(array $config)
    {
        $primary = $config["primary_host"];
        $secondary = $config["secondary_host"];
        try {
            $config["host"] = $primary;
            return parent::connect($config);
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
            $config["host"] = $secondary;
            return parent::connect($config);
        }
    }
}
```

Create a service provider to bind your custom DB connector:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class CustomMysqlConnector extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('db.connector.mysql', \App\Database\MySqlConnector::class);
    }
}
```

Register your provider in the application config.

```php
<?php

return [
    ...
    'providers' => [
        ...
        App\Providers\CustomMysqlConnector::class,
    ],
];
```

Unset the `host` key in your configuration array. Instead, use `primary_host` and `secondary_host` as used in the custom connector.

Comment: This helped me, i was able to solve it this way, thank you.